# c# object does not contain definition error

Tags: c#

I'm creating a winform which can read data from another winform but i receive some errors in my functions :

```
namespace stackkcw
  {
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public TcpClient client;
        private object datgdStock;
        private object lablUpdates;
        private object lablTime;
        private int countOfData;



        public Form1()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
        }
       private void UpdateGrid(StockDetails data)
        {

            datgdStock.Rows[data.StockId].Cells[0].Value = data.StockName;
            datgdStock.Rows[data.StockId].Cells[1].Value = data.StockPrice;
            datgdStock.Rows[data.StockId].Cells[2].Value = data.StockChange;

        }
        private void UpdateLbl(StockDetails data)
        {
            countOfData++;  

            lablUpdates.Invoke(new Action(() => lablUpdates.Text =          countOfData.ToString()));
            lablTime.Invoke(new Action(() => lablTime.Text = data.Time.ToString()));

        }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataReceiver data = new DataReceiver();



            data.connect(IPAddress.Parse(textBox1.Text), int.Parse(textBox2.Text));
            // Pass input in txtIP as an IPAddress and the input in txtPort as an int.
            button1.Enabled = false; // Disable button connect on valid data sending to data reciever class.
            textBox1.Enabled = false; // Disable ip text box on valid data sending to data receiver class
            textBox2.Enabled = false; // disable port text box on valid data sending to data receiver class
            data.dataRecieved += new DataReceiver.DataRecived(UpdateGrid);

            data.dataRecieved += new DataReceiver.DataRecived(UpdateLbl);


        }
        public struct StockDetails
        {

            public int StockId;
            public string StockName;
            public double StockPrice;
            public double StockChange;
            public DateTime Time;
        }
        class DataReceiver
        {
            public delegate void DataRecived(StockDetails stockData);
            public event DataRecived dataRecieved;
            StockDetails data;

            private TcpClient StockClient;

            private Thread listeningThread = null;

            public void connect(IPAddress ip, int port)
            {
                StockClient = new TcpClient();
                StockClient.Connect(ip, port);

                MessageBox.Show("Connected to: " + ip.ToString());

                listeningThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(listen));
                listeningThread.Start();
            }


            public void listen()
            {
                NetworkStream stream = StockClient.GetStream();

                while (true)
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
                    int no_of_bytes = stream.Read(buffer, 0, 256);

                    JavaScriptSerializer Serializer = new  JavaScriptSerializer();
                    data = Serializer.Deserialize<StockDetails>(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, no_of_bytes));

                    OnDataRecived();
                }

            }

            protected virtual void OnDataRecived()
            {
                dataRecieved(data);
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Now imagine someone looking at your code and trying to figure out what is the error you receive. What do you think it will be its reaction when he/she realizes that you have all this information but at the end of this wall of code you didn't provide it?

Comment: "but i receive some errors"... and how about telling us what these errors are?

Comment: Sorry. The errors are : Object does not contain definiton for " Text "  and no extension method "Text" accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found. And same goes for Row and Invoke.

Comment: And now you expect us to find the exact line in your wall of code? Is this a riddle or do you eventually tell us the line that your compiler complains about?

Comment: Lines : 36-37-38 and 45-46.

Comment: `lablUpdates` and `lablTime` are declared as `object`. I _guess_ you wanted to declare them as `Label`.

Comment: Please for your next question, take some time to think about this. Imagine you were to answer such a question. Provide as much information (but not more) needed to spot and understand the error. Your compiler exactly tells you what went wrong and where. We're all volunteers. I just spotted the mistake accidently, but noone here will coutn your lines of code to find lines "36,37,38". Simply highlight them, or repeat them or even better reduce your code to an [mcve].

Comment: You are completely right. I'm kind of new to the website and yes. I will take more time next time when i ask a question. Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D not use object for these properties

```
 private DataGridView datgdStock;
        private TextBox lablUpdates;
        private TextBox lablTime;
```

Comment: thank you very much